# Google Application Engine + Tiles = Error 500 null

Tags: google-app-engine, struts2, tiles

I'm building and application using Google Application Engine together with Struts2 + Tiles.
Here is my configuration.

web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
  </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>services</param-name>
    <param-value/>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

  <package name="user" extends="struts-default">
    <result-types>
      <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
    </result-types>

    <action name="Login">
      <result type="tiles">login.page</result>
    </action>
    <action name="Welcome" class="net.nahoot.web.culturewatch.action.WelcomeUserAction">
      <result type="tiles" name="SUCCESS">wellcome.page</result>
     </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

tiles.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

  <!-- common layout components -->
  <definition name="baselayout.page" template="/baseLayout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/header.jsp" />
  </definition>


  <definition name="login.page" extends="baselayout.page" >
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/User/pages/login.jsp" />
  </definition>

  <definition name="wellcome.page" extends="baselayout.page" >
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/User/pages/wellcome_user.jsp" />
  </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

The result, when I call `http://localhost:8888/culturewatchweb/Login`, is: Error 500 null

On the log I see:

```
10/Jan/2013 19:09:09 org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer render
WARNING: Unable to find the definition 'null'
10/Jan/2013 19:09:09 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error
SEVERE: Exception occurred during processing request: null
org.apache.tiles.definition.NoSuchDefinitionException
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:578)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult.doExecute(TilesResult.java:105)
    at     org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    at     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:367)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:271)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:544)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:383)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

But I don't understand where that null is coming from.
What am I not seeing?

Comment: please post your libraries with version number

Comment: Do the other actions with tiles results work?

Comment: @Jaiwo99: here are the libs https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3501880/libs.png
No action works. I can't even access the index.html file inside web directory. Although in this case I get a 404 instead of a 500.

Comment: Hello,
no one is able to get tiles (and struts, but not spring) working with Google Application Engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should turn off OGNL security manager - it is performing security checking, which is not support in GAE. Create listener and turn it on in the web.xml:

my.listener.GAESecurityFixListener.java

```java
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionAttributeListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

import ognl.OgnlRuntime;

public class Struts2ListenerOnGAE implements ServletContextListener,
        HttpSessionListener, HttpSessionAttributeListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        OgnlRuntime.setSecurityManager(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void attributeAdded(HttpSessionBindingEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void attributeRemoved(HttpSessionBindingEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void attributeReplaced(HttpSessionBindingEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

web.xml:

```xml
<web-app>
....
    <listener>
        <listener-class>my.listener.GAESecurityFixListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked. The dumb think is that I had that when I was just configuring struts. But then I removed it when I added the StrutsTilesListener.

Answer (score 0):

try add this in your `web.xml`:

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.tiles.definition.DefinitionsFactory.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

**UPDATE**
seems this is your problem, that you should extends `` `tiles-default `` in your package

```
<package name="user" extends="struts-default, tiles-default">
```

Comment: I've tried it, but it still doesn't work.
But, even without the context-param, I think that by default tiles looks for the file there... because I can see this when I initialize the server:
11/Jan/2013 10:55:03 org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer init
INFO: Initializing Tiles2 container. . .
11/Jan/2013 10:55:04 org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer initializeDefinitionsFactory
INFO: Tiles2 container initialization complete.

Comment: No, still the NoSuchDefinitionException.

Comment: @Nahoot does `http://localhost:8888/culturewatchweb/Login` work? I find nowhere your action definition of `Login`

Comment: No it doesn't, that's exactly why I'm asking for help. :) I get an error 500. I have the  action `<action name="Login">` in my struts file. It should forward to my login.page tiles but, aparently, something is failing.

Comment: @Nahoot I understand now! this should be the default action, which means you need add `<default-action-ref name="Login">` to your configuration, if there is no such action in the namespace found, struts2 will redirect it to the default action to you.

Comment: The default action is a nice to know. I wasn't aware of that. But it doesn't solve the issue. On my URL (`http://localhost:8888/culturewatchweb/Login`) I already explicitly call my action. The problem is somewhere inside struts/tiles. For some reason something becomes null and sends back an exception.